# On Plus of empty string

Tags: formal-languages, automata

We know $L^+=L^\star\backslash\{\epsilon\}$. How do we interpret that $\{\epsilon\}^+=\{\epsilon\}$?

Comment: "We know that $L^+ = L^*\setminus\{\varepsilon\}$." No we don't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I meant when $\epsilon\notin L$ and $L$ is an alphabet set

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question to make it clearer. If you write $L$, _everybody_ is going to assume you're talking about a language, not an alphabet. And when you write $\{\epsilon\}^+$, you _are_ talking about applying $(\cdot)^+$ to a language, rather than the alphabet consisting of just the symbol $\epsilon", right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first definition only holds if $\epsilon \notin L$.

The Kleene star and plus are defined using recursive sets $V_i$. We have:

$$V_0 = \{\epsilon\}$$
$$V_1 = L$$
$$V_{i+1} = \{ vw : v \in V_i \wedge w \in L\}$$

Then:

$$L^* = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} V_i$$
$$L^+ = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} V_i$$

Note that $L^+$ *omits* $V_0 = \{\epsilon\}$, but does not subtract $\epsilon$ from $L$.